# How to create gated content using ACF + plugin

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-login

I'm looking to create gated content using some sort of plugin with ACF.
Do any of you have experience with this?

The Gated content should be hidden from people that are not signed in.
I would like to create the user accounts myself and send the account information to the users - the users should not be able to register themselves.

I would also like to hide specific content on the page, rather than a full page.
Just like if you read an online newspaper and are prompted with a payment wall.
However, I don't need a subscription or payments for this solution - I simply need to hide content for regular users and show it if the users are signed in.

Any help is much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Maybe this can help , a plugin with roles for the blocks: https://wordpress.org/plugins/block-permissions/

Comment: It looks good, but I need a reliable plugin - this only has one review. But thanks for the tip @ITgoldman

Comment: Welcome to SO. Sorry, but this question is off-topic here.  [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) specifically - `Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.` Instead, please try to better describe your problem and what you have done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Within the template of the block you can use logic like this:

```
<p>content for everyone</p>
<?php
if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    echo "<p>hello, logged in user</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p>hello, guest</p>";
}
?>
```

Comment: The users should not have access to the backend. 
How would you restrict them to only have access to the frontend?
I was looking at https://memberpress.com/ but it seems kinda overkill for what i'm looking for. What do you think? Thank you for helping out!

Comment: Then you need to block their access by redirecting them after login. Maybe this plugin will work https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-dashboard-access-for-non-admins/